# Migrating SharePoint 2010 Enterprise to SharePoint 2013 Standard

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, upgrade, migrate, license, sharepoint-standard

If we migrate a `SharePoint Server 2010` with `Enterprise Client Access License` to a `SharePoint Server 2013 with Standard Client Access License`, would we have issues?

I presume we will have issues as this seems an upgrade in version but a downgrade in edition. I would like to hear your thoughts and experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an easy job as it is not supported path of Migration. In your situation, I highly recommend using the 3rd party tools(ShareGate, Metalogix etc).

Another Option, I am thinking( complex, required a lot of work).

- Build a new 2010 std farm.
- Deactivate ent features from current 2010 farm
- detach Content Db from Prod 2010 and attach to 2010 Std farm.
- Test it and test it.
- if everything goes well then migrate from here to 2013.

Answer (score 1):

You can not directly upgrade from `SharePoint 2010 Enterprise` to `SharePoint 2013 Standard` as mentioned in MSDN link given below.

Please find table under `Supported editions for upgrade` in below given link.

[Review supported editions and products for upgrading to SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/cc262747.aspx)

If you want to upgrade from `SharePoint 2010` to `SharePoint 2013` than please follow guideline mentioned in below mentioned link.

[SharePoint 2010 to 2013 Upgrade Step-by-Step](https://sharepointengineer.com/2012/11/15/sharepoint-2010-to-2013-upgrade-step-by-step-2/)

Answer (score 0):

The SharePoint Standard Edition does not support InfoPath forms in both the SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint 2013. Therefore if your SharePoint sites contain InfoPath forms in SharePoint 2010 Enterprise, these will stop working in SharePoint 2013 Standard. There are other issues also that may come up. Check the list of features between the editions given in the link below to make this decision.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sharepointcomic/2010/07/20/compare-sharepoint-2010-editions/

Answer (score -1):

SharePoint 2013 has a new configuration option called "[licensing](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219627.aspx)". You can enable and disable license-depended features for a group of users.

My Idea:

- Install your SharePoint 2013 environment with an Enterprise License key.
- Enable licensing via PowerShell. Assign only Standard-Licenses to your users
- Migrate your content database according to [Microsoft's guidiance](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262483.aspx)

**Important: As i am not a licensing expert, you should review my advice with your licensing-partner!**