# SharePoint 2013 Downgrade from Enterprise to Standard

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, upgrade, sharepoint-farm

While setting up a Sp 2013 farm we used a enterprise key by mistake. Now 3 weeks later we realised the goof up. Is it possible to downgrade from enterprise to standard. As creating new farm from scratch would put us in a tough situation with everything ready to go live.

Comment: No, you cannot downgrade.

Comment: Read on some forums that downgrade can be achieved by deactivating and uninstalling some features? Is it possible?

Comment: Well, if the problem is paying for a enterprise key, you should set up a new environment and copy the content databases to the new environment (it's important that all enterprise features are deactivated, otherwise the databases won't work). If you are fine to pay for a enterprise key but not use it's feature, you should be able to disable most of the enterprise features using PowerShell. Uninstalling features does not sound to safe and you might end up breaking a core service.

Answer (score 4):

As already mentioned by others, there is no supported way to downgrade from enterprise to standard edition.

Possible workaround:

SharePoint 2013 has a configuration option called "[licensing](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219627.aspx)". You can enable and disable license-depended features for a group of users.

HowTo:

- Enable licensing via PowerShell.
- Assign Standard-Licenses to all of your users (for example "Domain Users" group in ActiveDirectory).
- Do not assign an Enterprise-License.

I was downvoted for that idea in [another post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/179917/migrating-sharepoint-2010-enterprise-to-sharepoint-2013-standard/180024#180024) with no reason, but i still say it is a technical working solution. It is just important to get the OK from your licensing advocates.

Comment: In that case I think you still need an Enterprise server license and standard cal licenses.

Comment: That is correct. But there is no difference in pricing between standard and enterprise Server-License. You just get a different key for installation. Only the CALs have a different pricing.

Comment: This is the best answer here if you REALLY don't want to reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, short and simple:

> Once you go Enterprise, you can't go back.

One thing I know is, that the issue is that the content database will have these Enterprise features 'baked in' and those can't be changed.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported per [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262747.aspx#editions).

[image]